# SQL-Create a new column based off existing column from results list

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, alter-table

I have a SQL Query in Google BigQuery which collects all the information I need properly. However My 5th column, 'NewcustomerOverride" yields numerical answers that don't mean much at first glance, and I'd like to make it easier for the teams I need to share my list with. The way I want to do this is to create a new column based of the "NewCustomerOverride" column, namely 'ValueDescription'.

See Results image below.

[Results Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUySv.png)

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
A.PARTNER as CustomerNumber,
A.NAME_ORG1 as CustomerName,
B.VWERK as DeliveringPlant,
B.ZZ_FIRST_SALEDATE as FirstSaleDate,
C.ATWRT as NewCustomerOverride,
FROM `gcp-gfs-datalake-core-prd.sap_p05__saphanadb__views_current.but000`A
left join `gcp-gfs-datalake-core-prd.sap_p05__saphanadb__views_current.knvv`B
on A.PARTNER = B.KUNNR
left join `gcp-gfs-datalake-core-prd.sap_p05__saphanadb__views_current.ausp`C
on C.OBJEK = B.KUNNR
WHERE A.BU_GROUP = '0001'
AND A.XBLCK != 'X'
AND B.VWERK in ('1009','1020')
AND C.ATINN ='0000000007'
```

And here is what I tried to use to create a new column, but it is not working:

```
ALTER TABLE `C.ATWRT`
ADD COLUMN ValueDescription
CASE ValueDescription
When '1' Then 'Not New'
When '2' THEN 'Not New But Tracking New Sales'
When '3' THEN 'New'
```

Could use your help to see what I am doing wrong in my Alter Table to create my new column.

Thanks.

Tried using an alter table expression to add my column, it did not work.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: My reputation is too low for me to be able to include images - it automatically converts to a link. Sorry!

Comment: Not sure how that relates to my comment asking you to use editable text rather than images (or links to images)?

Comment: you can't include CASE logic in an ALTER TABLE command.  you have to add the column in one step and then do an UPDATE on the table to populate the new column with values

Comment: and you can just include a CASE statement in your query, you don't need to persist it as a physical column

Comment: Thanks, I just used the CASE statement and was able to make it work!